# 2 Different objects in a Retrofit response

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I have a Retrofit request which can reply two different Json responses *one response at a time*. I want to catch both cases in onResponse. So what i did is create a BaseResponse class

```
data class ResponseBase(val responseClass: ResponseClass?, val errorClass: ErrorClass?)
```

and the two inside class are like that.

```
data class ResponseClass(
        val config: Config
)

// Config class
data class Config(
        val acceptGuest: Int,
        val name: String,
        val host: Long
)
```

And the Error Class is like that

```
data class ErrorResponse(
    val error: Error
)

data class Error(
    val id: String,
    val message: String
)
```

So i guess that if the response json comes then i will have the responseClass object otherwise i will have the ErrorObject.

So when i get the following json response from Server which matches the ResponseClass i have an exception.

```
{"config":{"acceptGuest":0,"name":"server name","host":100}}
```

**Unable to invoke no-args constructor for retrofit2.Call<....ResponseClass>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem**

What am i missing..?

Comment: Add your API implementation

Comment: You are missing a deserializer. Retrofit does not support converting json response to your data class. You need to use a deserializer, eg. Gson, Moshi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use a GSON converter in my retrofit builder.

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit.Builder {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
    }
```